# How to stay in the UK after the exchange program?

Tags: visa, student-visa, uk-visa, students, erasmus

I'm going as a university exchange student to the UK (to Bradford University) for 6 months. The program I'm participating is the Erasmus+. The visa I'm applying for is a short-term student visa.

Is there a way to stay in the University afterwards, to finish my studies there?

I'm not a European citizen.